# Http Request Timeout using Cozyroc for connecting to Salesforce

Tags: ssis, timeout, salesforce

I have a SSIS package for transferring some data from SQL server to Salesforce and back, using Cozyroc SSIS+ library. The package is composed of multiple data flow tasks. It always seems to fail due to an HTTP connection timeout at one particular executable in one of the tasks. The executable, basically, tries to fetch some data from the Account object in Salesforce. There are other executables, earlier in the package which connect to and download data from Salesforce just fine, including the Account object. The stack trace is as follows:

```
Event Name: OnError
 Message: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at CozyRoc.SqlServer.SSIS.GzipWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at CozyRoc.Sforce.Service.SforceService.query(String queryString)
   at CozyRoc.SqlServer.SSIS.SforceSource.PreExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
 Operator: 
 Source Name: DailyJob
 Source ID: {63F0DB1D-84FA-40E6-BDF4-3C375F839630}
 Execution ID: {C92AE13A-A0EE-467F-925B-0520654E3E45}
 Start Time: 
 End Time: 
 Data Code: -1073450910
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing the timeout parameter in the Salesforce connection manager.

Comment: How is it possible for someone to down-vote the answer of the creator the COZYROC SSIS+ library where the question is exactly related to the COZYROC SSIS+ library? Whoever made the vote is simply not legit.

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. The timeout parameter is not the issue since previous calls did go through fine, as mentioned in the question.